# Weird replace behavior

Tags: javascript, string, format

I have tried creating a String.format function in JS like C# so I don't have to do `foo + ", " + bar` and do `"{0}, {1}".format(foo, bar);` I have got some pretty good results with this only using `{0}`.

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var replacement = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        replacement += this.replace("{" + i + "}", arguments[i]);
    }

    return replacement;
};
```

Except doing `"{0} {1}".format("foo", "bar");` comes out with: `foo {0}{1} bar` or a SyntaxError. I have never had any errors with replace like this before though.

Comment: Why are you appending the entire string every time? Also, what if a replacement contains `{1}`?

Comment: If you would have read my question more carefully you can see I am replacing {0}, {1} with the argument index. And also, I said there is weird behavior when using {1}. Please read my full question first.

Comment: Removed C# tag. Somehow SO automatically put it in and I have no idea why. And do you have to be so critical about it? This is one reason I don't use SO.

Comment: I think you need to read @SLaks's comment more closely (and take the attitude down a notch or three). (Word to the wise: SLaks is a pretty bright cookie.)

Comment: Read my comment more carefully.  `+=` appends the entire string.

Comment: *facepalm* It adds on a string. `foo += bar` is basically `foo = foo + bar`

Comment: Beware; if a replacement value contains `{1}`, bad things will happen.

Comment: @C.Morgan @SLaks is right. Appending the result of `this.replace` on each iteration will continuously add repeated instances of the entire string to `replacement`. Before saying _facepalm_, maybe you should reread him comment.

Comment: @C.Morgan I pasted your method into a CodePen to demonstrate his point, because you obviously couldn't be bothered to read the comments properly: http://codepen.io/jamesseanwright/pen/ozJEbG

Comment: <sarcasm>That message could not be nicer.</sarcasm>

Comment: Just because I am disabled doesn't mean you have to make fun of me like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var replacement = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var regexp = new RegExp('\\{'+i+'\\}', 'gi');
        replacement = replacement .replace(regexp, arguments[i]);
    }
    return replacement;
};
```

Comment: Totally works. For some reason SO won't let me mark this as answered

Comment: @C.Morgan: There's a 15-minute guard. After that, you can mark an answer.

Comment: Yeah, just about to say that

Comment: @vivek: No need for the `i` flag if there are no alpha characters in the regex (which there aren't).

Comment: This will break if a replacement contains `{1}`.

Comment: Search for sprintf in JavaScript also. It's quite useful in these scenarios

Answer (score 2):

The best way to approach this is with the function callback on `replace` and a global replacement search:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "format", {
  value: function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(m, c0) {
      return args[c0] || "";
    });
  }
});
console.log("testing {0}, {1}, {2}".format("one", "two", "three"));
```

A couple of reasons this is better than calling `replace` repeatedly:

- You don't have to rescan the entire string repeatedly
- Having `{n}` in a replacement won't cause trouble.

Note that I'm using `Object.defineProperty` to avoid creating an enumerable property on `String.prototype`.

The regex works by capturing any digits between `{}`. Then we use the resulting capture to look up the replacement on the original `arguments` given to `String.prototype.format`.

Note the `|| ""`. That will replace `{47}` with nothing if there aren't 48 arguments. If you prefer to leave the `{47}` in place, just change that to `|| m` instead.

In ES2015 and above, we'd do it like this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "format", {
  value: function(...args) {
    return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, (m, c0) => args[c0] || "");
  }
});
console.log("testing {0}, {1}, {2}".format("one", "two", "three"));
```

Comment: @C.Morgan: Sorry, I made at least three mistakes in the initial post. At least. :-| Fixed now.

Comment: This is relatively similar to one of these answers

Comment: @C.Morgan: What answers? Oh, and I added a note about the `|| ""` in case you wanted `|| m` instead, see above.